# How to replace comma separated text values in a column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle12c

[image: Sample Data]

I have a table `t1` with a varchar col `V_RELNIST_SKEY` which contains comma separated numbers between 1 and 12 as shown. I want to write a select statement to replace numbers by string. For e.g., value `5,6` should be replaced by `five,six` and so on.

```
|V_RELNIST_SKEY|
|6             |
|5,6           |
|1,12          |
|1,2,3,12      |
```

Comment: you mean these values are in the table and you've to update them? how many different combinations of numbers can you have, if they are comma-separated?

Comment: No, I do not need to update them. I need to select them as string. There can be any number of combinations, but the comma separated values are between 1 and 12 only.

Comment: what's the maximum number of commas you can have?

Comment: 11 commas is the maximum I can have

Comment: In all such problems, create a "correspondence" or "dictionary" table, having the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... in one column and the values 'one', 'two', 'three', ... (or 'A', 'B', 'C') in the other. You can do that either as a stored table or as an inline view (a subquery), perhaps in a WITH clause. Then split the comma-separated strings into component tokens, keeping track of their order - MT0 shows one of the many ways to do that. Then join to the "correspondence" dictionary and re-aggregate, perhaps with LISTAGG (beware the string length limit though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) as
 SELECT '9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT '6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT '1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT '2,3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT '5,6,7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT '8,4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT value,
       column_value AS words
FROM   test_data t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LISTAGG(
                      TO_CHAR(
                        TO_DATE(
                          REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '\d+', 1, LEVEL ),
                          'J'
                        ),
                        'JSP'
                      ),
                      ','
                    ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, '\d+' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) w;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE                      WORDS                                  
-------------------------- ----------------------------------------
9                          NINE                                    
6                          SIX                                     
1                          ONE                                     
2,3                        TWO,THREE                               
5,6,7                      FIVE,SIX,SEVEN                          
8,4                        EIGHT,FOUR                              
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,
                           NINE,TEN,ELEVEN,TWELVE
```

**Update**

> What if I have to replace 1 with A, 2 with B, 3 with C and so on?

```
SELECT value,
       COLUMN_VALUE AS words
FROM   test_data t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LISTAGG(
                      CHR( 64 + REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) ),
                      ','
                    ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, '\d+' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) w;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE                      WORDS                                  
-------------------------- ----------------------------------------
9                          I                                       
6                          F                                       
1                          A                                       
2,3                        B,C                                     
5,6,7                      E,F,G                                   
8,4                        H,D                                     
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I have to replace 1 with A, 2 with B, 3 with C and so on?

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi Updated

Comment: Ugh... really? `chr(64 + ....)`? Everything else looks fine, but in my imaginary IT business this wouldn't pass code review (if I understand correctly what that means).

Comment: @mathguy I could rewrite it as `CASE REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) WHEN 1 THEN 'A' WHEN 2 THEN 'B' WHEN 3 THEN 'C' ... END` if you want?

Comment: I would create a table or an inline view (perhaps in a WITH clause) with the correspondences, then do a join. Perhaps less efficient, but easier to maintain.